# Website in IIS with tomcat connection

Tags: java, iis, iis-7.5, tomcat6

I have a Web Site in IIS 7.5 (mysite), and i have configure bindings as

```
Type    Host Name            Port    IP Address
------------------------------------------------
http    test.mydomain.com    80      *
```

It serves some static content e.g. `http://test.mydomain.com/images/image1.jpg` and it is connected with application `myJavaApp` with tomcat.

`http://test.mydomain.com/myJavaApp/` serves the java app correctly.

I have configure the `hosts` file of the server so the domain `test.mydomain.com` point at `192.168.0.8` (static ip).

The problem is that when i call `http://test.mydomain.com:8080` tomcat does not response and i get the error `The server at test.mydomain.com is taking too long to respond.`

But when i call `http://localhost:8080` or `http://192.168.0.8:8080` tomcat response as i was excpecting.

I tried to config tomcat (server.xml) as

```
 <Host name="test.mydomain.com"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
        xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
 </Host>
```

but it didn't work. All calls are local calls.

Comment: When you browse these URL's, is the browser on the same server that got its `hosts` file hacked up?

Comment: yes all it's done from the same machine

Comment: Your browser uses its own DNS resolver/cache, gets a bad address for test.mydomain.com from the public DNS, and the machine at that address has port 8080 filtered by a firewall?

Comment: write it as answer to confirm it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your browser uses its own DNS resolver/cache, gets a bad address for test.mydomain.com from the public DNS, and the machine at that address has port 8080 filtered by a firewall?

Comment: I had open the port 8080 in firewall, but i didn't think the browser dns. Thanks